# How to position at the center one element with display flex

Tags: css, flexbox

I have container with div elemenents

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}
```

How to make one element positioned at the center on this block, and others to be `space-between`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container div {
  height: 50px;
}

.one,
.four,
.seven {
  background-color: red;
  width: 200px;
}

.two,
.six {
  background-color: green;
  width: 100px;
}

.three,
.five {
  background-color: yellow;
  width: 150px;
}

.center {
  width: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="one"></div>
  <div class="two"></div>
  <div class="three"></div>
  <div class="center"></div>
  <div class="four"></div>
  <div class="five"></div>
  <div class="six"></div>
  <div class="seven"></div>
</div>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khe3k9qg/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on how dynamic you want this to be, here is a suggestion where the items on the left and on the right side of the `center` element are wrapped.

The `left` and `right` get 50% each minus the width of the `center` (150px for each side), which will put the `center` in the middle.

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/khe3k9qg/2/)

Stack snippet

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container div {
  height: 50px;
}

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 150px);
}

.one,
.four,
.seven {
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 200px;
}

.two,
.six {
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis: 100px;
}

.three,
.five {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-basis: 150px;
}

.center {
  flex-basis: 300px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="one">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
    </div>
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="four">
    </div>
    <div class="five">
    </div>
    <div class="six">
    </div>
    <div class="seven">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

---

By adding a pseudo to each side wrapper, we can also make it behave similar to how `space-between` work without the wrappers (though still with `center` centered).

In this [fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/khe3k9qg/3/) (and below Stack snippet) I changed the width's so one easier can see how it behaves in full screen.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.container div {
  height: 50px;
}

.left, .right {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  flex-basis: calc(50% - 100px);
}

.left::after,
.right::before {
  content: '';
}

.one,
.four,
.seven {
  background-color: red;
  flex-basis: 125px;
}

.two,
.six {
  background-color: green;
  flex-basis: 25px;
}

.three,
.five {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex-basis: 75px;
}

.center {
  flex-basis: 200px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <div class="left">
    <div class="one">
    </div>
    <div class="two">
    </div>
    <div class="three">
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="center">
  </div>

  <div class="right">
    <div class="four">
    </div>
    <div class="five">
    </div>
    <div class="six">
    </div>
    <div class="seven">
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```